# implement something for/in/on/with something?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, word-usage, sentence

Which preposition is correct to use in the following sentence?:

> Implementation of this technique for/in/on/with complex objects is complicated

(meaning: it is complicated to apply this technique to complex objects.)

Answer (score 9):

There's no single correct usage here.

If you use *in*, that means you're implementing the technique *inside* of a complex object (for instance, it could be a piece of code contained within the object, or a piece of machinery inside of it). If you use *for*, then you're saying the technique operates on complex objects or for the benefit of complex objects. If you use *with*, you're implying that the technique is in conjunction with complex objects. *On*, however, does not "feel" right in conjunction with "implementation."

Given the meaning you're seeking, *for* seems like the best alternative.

Comment: what if I used "application" instead of "implementation"?

Comment: You answered this question in your question above: "application . . .  to."